# How to keep a variable value constant where its method is called in onCreate() method?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating a simple android application which shows no.of times a button is clicked in another activity. My problem is I am performing intent and count increment in the same method i.e onClick() of the button in the first activity. My problem is the count is resetting when ever i come back to the first fragment what should i do now.

this is my first activity onCreate() method.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Previous = findViewById(R.id.PreButton);
    PreTextView = findViewById(R.id.PreCount);
    previousIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
    previous();
    nxtClickCount();
}

public void previous() {
    mainActivity2 = new MainActivity2();
    Previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            count++;
            Log.i(TAG, "onClick 2 : " + count);
            startActivity(previousIntent);
            PreTextView.setText("Next Button Count Is " + mainActivity2.count);
        }
    });
}
```

This is my second activity onCreate() method.

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Next = findViewById(R.id.Nxtbutton);
    NxtTextView = findViewById(R.id.NxtCount);
    nextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    next();
    preClickCount();
}

public void next() {
    mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            count++;
            Log.i(TAG, "onClick: " + count);
            startActivity(nextIntent);
            NxtTextView.setText("Previous Button Count Is " + mainActivity.count);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should keep the variable as STATIC.

Here I have made my count variable as static. In my question I have not done that.

```
Button Next;
TextView NxtTextView;
Intent nextIntent;
public static int count = 0;
MainActivity2 mainActivity2;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Next = findViewById(R.id.Nxtbutton);
    NxtTextView = findViewById(R.id.NxtCount);
    nextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);

    next();
    preClickCount();
}

public void next() {
    mainActivity2 = new MainActivity2();
    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            count++;
            Log.i(TAG, "onClick: " + count);
            startActivity(nextIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Glad this works for you! Just be warned that sometimes the OS will clean up static references (for example, when you minimise the app to say take a phone call or a photo or something). So you might want to look into the savedInstance stuff anyway in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Activity in Android is created by system when you start it, you should never 'new' an Activity.
Share data between activites, you can use `Intent.putExtra("myCount", count)` in your fist activity, and `Intent.getInt("myCount")` in your second activity.

And you can also use Application (Define your own App class extends Application class, and define count in App, don't forget put you App in AndroidManifest.xml), you can use `((App)Context.getApplication).count` to access your 'count' in Activity/Service and etc.

Related method you should konw is `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult`, this related method make you have chance to getback the data from second activity.

Comment: Thanks @Vicky But I have found a simple solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save and retrieve the value using onSaveInstanceState() and, in onCreate(), retrieving the value from the saved state:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: @DpD please post your answer for people that might have the same problem in the future :)